# distanceTo is giving wrong result in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, distance

I am using `distanceTo` from OpenLayers to calculate the distance between two locations

These are map details:

```
  Geographic  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
  Mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");  

   map = new OpenLayers.Map({
   div: "map_canvas",
   projection: Mercator,
   displayProjection: Geographic,
   center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
   minResolution: "auto",
   minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
   maxResolution: "auto",
   maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90),
   units : 'km'
});
```

these are my lat and lon values

```
lat = 47.162494, lon = 19.503304
lat = 46.2525684, lon = 20.147060499999952
```

google maps function result is `111861.5962110549`

```
function distanceBetweenMarkers(latlng1, latlng2){
    return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1, latlng2);
}
```

openlayers function result `6237980.800397318`

```
function distanceBetweenMarkers(latlng1, latlng2){
        var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng1.lon, latlng1.lat);
        var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng2.lon, latlng2.lat);
        return point1.distanceTo(point2);
    }
```

Why is the difference between google maps `computeDistanceBetween` and openlayers `distanceTo?`

Comment: I wonder where your (lon,lat) coordinates come from: look at how far apart the longitudes are! If they are correct, then these points must be almost a third of the way around the globe from each other (within Szeged and Indianapolis, I believe). If the earth were only 107 miles in diameter, then that distance would indeed be 100 miles. The earth hasn't shrunk that much yet :-). Because its diameter really is 12,706,000 meters, the actual distance is about 11,807,000 meters--not too far from your calculation, which is not bad considering you are using the high-distortion Mercator projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use **getGeodesicLength**.

it works for calculating the approximate length of the geometry were it projected onto the earth.

distanceTo method works for planar measure which handle the world as a flat using cartesian coordinates. getting approximately the accurate results , you should use geodesic measurament for your project.

```
var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng1.lon, latlng1.lat);
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlng2.lon, latlng2.lat);

var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([p1, p2]);
alert(line.getGeodesicLength(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")));
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: i want to replicate the google maps google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1, latlng2)

Comment: Ramesh, if the Google maps result truly is 100 miles as you still claim in your edited question, then there's something seriously wrong that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: hi @whuber, can u suggest me what i have to use in openlayers to get the same result with google maps above function.

Comment: What result does Google Maps give, Ramesh?  I don't believe it would tell you those cities are 100 miles apart!

Comment: hi @whuber i have updated the code. please look into it..

Comment: this method results in METERS. comparing with Haversine's, i found up to 0.5% difference. UPVOTED :)